# Inflate Exception Binary Xml File at line #2

Tags: android, exception, nullpointerexception

i am using the ADT Bundle provided by android, previously i was using the normal eclipse with ADT plugin my apps were working fine, but now after using the new ADT Bundle my apps crashes after displaying the splash screen.

Here is stacktrace :

```
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.webrich.grealgebra/com.aaa.bbb.activity.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2063)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2088)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:126)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1168)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4561)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:800)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:729)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:266)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at com.webrich.base.activity.MainActivity.onCreation(MainActivity.java:50)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at com.webrich.base.activity.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:79)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4637)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2027)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     ... 11 more
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     ... 26 more
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-mdpi/navigation_tile_back.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020039
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1923)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2812)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:385)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:174)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:170)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     ... 29 more
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #2: <bitmap> requires a valid src attribute
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.inflate(BitmapDrawable.java:448)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:867)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:804)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1920)
06-21 19:10:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4493):     ... 34 more
```

But the same app works fine in the normal eclipse, please help me i am not able to figure it out why its happening so.

**EDIT**
here is the .xml which its not find.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/bar"
    android:tileMode="repeat" >
</bitmap>
```

Comment: post res/drawable-mdpi/navigation_tile_back.xml

Comment: looks good. bar is a png or a xml?

Comment: have you tried with to clean and rebuild?

Comment: @blackbelt i have tried several times, but no luck

Comment: is BaseActivity.java:79 the setContentView line?

Comment: @blackbelt i am just setting the layout as usual

Comment: can you post the layout?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32162/discussion-between-goofy-and-blackbelt)

Answer (score 0):

The error log says:
`<bitmap> requires a valid src attribute`

So it seems that your drawable "bar" is not correct.